# Remove html tags, but not <br>

Tags: regex, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I want to **convert an html string value to a string value with all the html tags removed, except for "br", which I want to replace with a newline character** (`vbNewline` constant). So I want the plain text from the html, but keep the newlines.

This does not look like a good solution, but it works as long as I don't have tags with quoted strings containing "<":

```
Public Function StringRemoveCharsAt (ByVal S, ByVal StartPos, ByVal Count)
    StringRemoveCharsAt=Left (S,StartPos-1) & Right (S,Len (S)-StartPos+1-Count)
End Function


Public Function StringRemoveTagsKeepNewlines (ByVal S)
    Dim R: Set R=New RegExp
    R.Global=true
    ' Matches everything, that does not start with a "<", does not contain a ">", and ends with ">" endet, as long as it is neither <br> nor <BR>:
    R.Pattern="(?!\<BR\>)(?!\<br\>)\<[^\>]*\>"
    Dim Matches: Set Matches=R.Execute (S)

    Dim Result: Result=S
    If Matches.Count > 0 Then
        Dim Index
        For Index = Matches.Count-1 to 0 step -1
            Dim Match: Set Match=Matches.Item (Index)
            Result=StringRemoveCharsAt (Result,Match.FirstIndex+1,Len (Match.Value))
        Next
    End If
    StringRemoveTagsKeepNewlines=Result
End Function
```

The question is not whether it is a good idea to use a regex to find the tags, I do understand it is not. The question is: **Can this code be improved easily in terms of reliability and speed?**

In particular, I have not found a better way (using regexes) than using a regex that matches all tags (except for "br"), and then loop over all matches, and remove them from the string. It cannot be that hard to get all non-tag text fragments (but including "br"), with a more simple loop just collecting all matches and appending them to the `Result` temp variable?

I do understand I could change this code (i.e. simplify the regexp) so it matches "br", too, and then filter out the "br" matches inside the loop after the `R.Execute` call. I left that in intentionally because I think negating the regexp is worth the trouble only if it also covers the br exceptional case.

P.S.: The `.GetROProperty ("innertext")` value in QTP/UFT test objects does the job, but it swallows all newlines, which we want to be included. That's the original context where this code came up: Compare expected and actual values, keeping the newlines, but ignoring the tags, in UFT, which also is the only reason why I tag this question with HP UFT.

This makes sense because multiline display value

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
```

shall not be compared (and matched) against "This is line 1This is line 2" but against "This is line1\nThis is line2" (we do read such values from data files, and replace the \n with vbNewline in the process, of course). Requirements dictating: I cannot get expected string values that contain html tags, or placeholders/wildcards for them.

Comment: If I understand well, your code is already working ?

Comment: Ehem, yes, provided tags don't contain quoted "<" or ">" characters, because I don't check for string quotes.

Comment: Sorry if you think it is stupid idea: Why do not you replace the "\n" in the expected text with an empty string "" and compare the value with actual 'innerText' which sounds more reliable to me.

Comment: Because then i would effectively ignore the line breaks, but their presence/absence should be relevant. Not a stupid idea, just a violation of the requirement ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should be doing this on the DOM, not a string. You can either write the VBScript based on the `.Object` property or you can use `RunScript` in order to perform it in JavaAcript. For your reference here's something I threw together in a few minutes that I think does what you want.

```
function text(node, text)  {
    switch(node.nodeType) {
        case node.ELEMENT_NODE:
            if (node.nodeName == 'BR')
                return '\n';
            return Array.prototype.map.call(node.childNodes, function(child) {
                return text(child);
            }).join('');
        case node.TEXT_NODE:
            return node.textContent;
    }
    return '';
}
```